# How to store Markdown in a JSON file

Tags: json

I am working on a Next.js blog and trying to use react-markdown to read Markdown data, but I found that I cant store Markdown in JSON files.

```
./data/hello.json
{
    "thumbnail" : "https://dummyimage.com/722x402",
    "slug" : "hello",
    "title" : "This is hello",
    "description" : "This is description",
    "category" : "hello",
    "content" : "


     #Hello
     **How are you**

",
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literal new lines are not allowed in the middle of JSON strings. Use `\n` to represent them instead.

Comment: is there any tool which can automatically put escape sequences in the string?

Comment: There is more that probably needs to be escaped, for example quotes "".

Comment: @OliverHausler — This answer identifies the problem with the code in the question. It doesn't attempt to be an exhaustive list of all characters that need escaping.

Comment: @Quentin Agreed, it identifies the problem with the code in the question, but does not fully answer the question itself. MD may contain quotes and the backslash character, while JSON cannot (unescaped). See JSON specification https://www.json.org/json-en.html